Use Pybind11 library created with MSYS2,CMake and Make in Python
I have just created a library with Pybind11 from the C++ side:
I did it with MSYS2 and CMake and Make. (I have GCC, Make, CMake and Pybind11 installed with the commands)
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-make
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pybind11

Here example.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("add", &add, "A function that adds two numbers");
}

Here CMakeLists.txt (in the same directory as example.cpp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

# Notre projet est étiqueté hello
project(example)

find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
find_package(pybind11 CONFIG)

# pybind11 method:
pybind11_add_module(example example.cpp)

Then I ran the commands
mkdir buildmingw
cd buildmingw
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
mingw32-make 

and a file example.cp311-win_amd64.pyd is produced.
How can I use this file now in Python?
I already tried putting test.py in the same directory as example.cp311-win_amd64.pyd and then I launched:
python test.py
where test.py looks like this:
import example

print( example.add(7,13 ) )

I get the error message:
D:\Informatik\NachhilfeInfoUni\KadalaSchmittC++\PythonBindC++\buildmingw4>python tes
t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Informatik\NachhilfeInfoUni\KadalaSchmittC++\PythonBindC++\buildmingw4\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import example
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing example: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

What do I do wrong? How can I correctly import my library?

Judging from its name, your pybind11 extension module is compiled against python 3.11. You probably want to check if the final invocation of python test.py is using a consistent version 3.11 of the python interpreter.
Alternatively, you can create a venv and invoke all commands (including pip install, cmake, make and python test.py) with the venv activated.

How can I find out, whether it is really compiled against python 3.11 ?? Or if not, against which other version? If I type python --version into my terminal, my version is 3.11.1 which should then be the correct one. I also managed to launch everything from a virtual environment, but there too, the python version is 3.11.1 and I get the same error message.

How can I check, whether my final invocation of python test.py is using a consistent version of the python interpreter. If I say python --version, it gives me 3.11.1

@user172501 Glad to hear you have solved it. Generally, that's the down-side of using extension modules -- you need to build against whatever target arch / ver / dialect you'd plan to support. My personal best practice is to use a wrapper package to hide the import / load of multiple extension modules targeting different platforms.

The Python version was indeed the problem.
I had one Python installed from Python for Windows
The other Python version was installed by MSYS2 without me being aware of it.
The first mentioned Python version was in a C:\Python directory and the path was configured correctly. I renamed this directory do C:\PythonHidden
Then I ran CMake and Make again as in the question.
Now the file example.cp311-mingw_x86_64.pyd was produced.
And that one I could import.
